# Desktop Issue - Low Perfomance and crash

Tags: performance, hardware-failure, shutdown

My pc gets really slow when I demand it (from my point of view). So I thought my HDD was broken and bought a new SSD instead. I reinstalled Windows 10 on my SSD and tried installing some programs. First of all, Visual Studio. While it is downloading and installing in parallel, I ran NvidiaExpierence. When I started the setup, my PC became very slow. During the process, I looked in the TaskManager and saw that none of my hardware (SSD, CPU, GPU, etc.) was over 50%. After 1-2 minutes of slowing down, the pc shut down immediately.
This problem repeated itself every time on the old system and now on the new one!

What could be the problem?

My PC Specs:

Mainboard: H100M,
CPU:       Intel Core i7-7700K,
GPU:       NVidia gtx 1060 6GB,
Memory:    8GB,
other:     Win 10 on SSD and HDD with some data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the manufacturer's Diagnostic Test App and test all hardware particularly memory.

If a white box PC, get test apps for each piece of hardware based on the manufacturer's brand of hardware.

Memory or main board issues would figure high because you replaced the drive and re-installed the operating system.

Memtest86.exe (https://www.memtest86.com/) can also be used to test memory.

Comment: All right, memtest86 found 32 Errors. Dam it!

Comment: So you need to replace the memory modules.  Good luck with this.